# Show that $z,z'$ correspond to diametrically opposite points on the Riemann sphere if and only if $z\overline{z'} = −1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that if complex numbers $z$ and $z^{\prime}$ correspond to opposite points on the Riemann sphere, then it must be the case that $z \bar{z}^{\prime}=-1$

Is the converse true, that $z \bar{z}^{\prime}=-1$ implies that the corresponding points on the Riemann sphere are opposite points?
I associate $\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}\right)$ with $z$ and $\left(x_{1}^{\prime}, x_{2}^{\prime}, x_{3}^{\prime}\right)$ with $z^{\prime}$. The usual correspondence gives
$$
z=\frac{x_{1}+i x_{2}}{1-x_{3}}, \quad z^{\prime}=\frac{x_{1}^{\prime}+i x_{2}^{\prime}}{1-x_{3}^{\prime}}
$$
Then I reach an equation
$$
z \bar{z}^{\prime}=\frac{x_{1}+i x_{2}}{1-x_{3}} \cdot \frac{x_{1}^{\prime}-i x_{2}^{\prime}}{1-x_{3}^{\prime}}=-1
$$
which implies
$$
x_{1} x_{1}^{\prime}+x_{2} x_{2}^{\prime}+x_{3} x_{3}^{\prime}+\left(x_{1}^{\prime} x_{2}-x_{1} x_{2}^{\prime}\right) i=-1+x_{3}+x_{3}^{\prime}
$$
Can one conclude that $\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}\right)=-\left(x_{1}^{\prime}, x_{2}^{\prime}, x_{3}^{\prime}\right)$ from this relation?

Comment: The converse statement follows from the fact that the stereographic projection is a *bijective* mapping between the sphere and the extended plane.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. You need to adjoin the conditions that $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $(x_1',x_2',x_3')$ belong to the sphere. From that system of three equations you can conclude what you need.

Comment: Isn't that implied by the question? It asks about *“... corresponding points on the Riemann sphere ...”*

Comment: Sure. But I had the impression that the OP wanted to conclude that the points are antipodal from his last equation only.